# Environment aligned undefined when trying to write a system of equations

Tags: errors, equations

I'm trying to write a system of equations in LaTeX. From the [Wiki page *Advanced Mathematics*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics) I took this example:

```
\begin{equation}
 \left.\begin{aligned}
        B'&=-\partial \times E,\\
        E'&=\partial \times B - 4\pi j,
       \end{aligned}
 \right\}
 \qquad \text{Maxwell's equations}
\end{equation}
```

but as a result I got:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment aligned undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.49  \left.\begin{aligned}
```

Does anybody know what goes wrong here?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. We can definitely assist you better in that way. More than likely, from the error message, your missing the `amsmath` package which defines the `aligned` environment.

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```